# Deployment and Code-First

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code first for my current project and am a little nervous about deployments.  How, would I ensure that the data in the databases in the live environment do not get overwritten by deployments subsequent to the first one.  Also, how are table changes managed?  In other words what happens when columns are added, removed, renamed and other similar changes?

Thanks,

Sachin